# Appengine appcfg.py vacuum_indexes stuck

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to remove unused indexes from my appengine app, but it seems like the command is stuck. I have ran it like 30 minutes ago, nothing is showing in my command line, indexes still exist in cloud console:

```
$ appcfg.py vacuum_indexes . --noisy
12:10 PM Host: appengine.google.com
12:10 PM Fetching index definitions diff.
2016-05-18 12:10:13,874 DEBUG appengine_rpc_httplib2.py:465 _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
2016-05-18 12:10:13,874 DEBUG appengine_rpc_httplib2.py:244 Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/datastore/index/diff?app_id=<myappname> headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '2154', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=indexes:
<indexes>
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: can you update us with the status now ?

Comment: not really sure what caused this problem, but when I used "git bash" console, it would get stuck, but when I tried using windows command line, for some reason it worked